# How to convert SQL table into a customised gridview

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview, pivot-table

I have a c# web page and i am using SQL for the database

i need to display the data from table into a gridview

SQL : I have a table as below

```
Exec_Date                     Plat       Pass     Fail 
----------------------------------------------------------------
 2017-02-19 12:32:43.570      MSSQL       10       12
 2017-02-19 12:32:43.570      MSSQL       10       12
 2017-02-18 12:32:43.570      Sybase      10       12
 2017-02-18 12:32:43.570      Oracle      10       12
```

i would like to convert the table into a customised format for a presentation

```
Status     18/02    19/02
-------------------------
Pass       20        20   
Fail       24        24
```

is the above possible to be done by Pivot ? if so can anyone give some idea on that pls?

I have tried the below so far and the @Names is not resolving the variable value in query

```
create table #TempTable
(Exec_Date  varchar(max),
 Pass  int,
 Ref_Status varchar(max)
 )


 Insert into #TempTable
 select  cast(Exec_Date as DATE) as Date,SUM(Pass) as Pass,'PASS' from F_Exec where cast(Exec_Date as DATE) >= '2017-02-17' and cast(Exec_Date as DATE) <= '2017-02-20'  group by  Exec_Date,Pass


DECLARE @Names varchar(max)
SELECT  @Names = COALESCE(@Names + '],[', '[') +  Exec_Date FROM #TempTable

select @Names=@Names+']'


 Select * from #TempTable pivot
(SUM(Pass) for Exec_Date IN (@Names) )as PivotTable
```

The variable @Names is not considered as variable. If i manually replace that resultant value from the variable it works

Comment: can you given more information about which technology are you uses in the presentation layer and what the language you use to map database data to view .

Comment: updated now.Pls chk

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
declare @tbl table (Exec_Date datetime, Plat varchar(max), Pass int, Fail int)

insert into @tbl(Exec_Date , Plat , Pass , Fail ) values
('2017-02-19 12:32:43.570', 'MSSQL',10,12),
('2017-02-19 12:32:43.570', 'MSSQL',10,12),
('2017-02-18 12:32:43.570', 'Sybase',10,12),
('2017-02-18 12:32:43.570', 'Oracle',10,12)

select * from
    (
        select Date,Status,sum(Success) success from 
        (

            select left(convert(varchar(20),Exec_Date,103),5) as [Date],Pass,Fail from @tbl
        ) as baseData

        unpivot
        (
            Success for Status in (Pass,Fail)

        ) as tblUnPivot

        group by date ,status
    ) as baseData

pivot
(
    sum(success)
    for Date in ([18/02],[19/02])
) as tblPivot

order by Status
```

Comment: how to get the dates [18/02],[19/02] dynamically and replace as variable ?

Select * from #TempTable pivot
(SUM(Pass) for Exec_Date IN (@DateRange) )as PivotTable

assume the @DateRange is consist of values like [2017-02-17],[2017-02-18],[2017-02-19],[2017-02-20]

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

declared nvarchar variable and concatenated the query & dynamic column names

```
 DECLARE @sqlstring nvarchar(MAX)
 SET @sqlstring =N'
 Select * from #TempTable pivot (SUM(Pass) for Exec_Date IN (' +@Names+') )as PivotTable;';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstring;
```